# Invertibility of $M_{m+1\times m+1}[i,j]=\frac{1}{2m+3-i-j}$

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

Please consider the following matrix

$$M_{m+1\times m+1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2m+1} & \frac{1}{2m} & \dots & \frac{1}{m+2}  & \frac{1}{m+1} \\
    \frac{1}{2m} & \frac{1}{2m-1} & \dots & \frac{1}{m+1}  & \frac{1}{m} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    \frac{1}{m+2} & \frac{1}{m+1} & \dots & \frac{1}{3}  & \frac{1}{2}\\
    \frac{1}{m+1} & \frac{1}{m} & \dots & \frac{1}{2}  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have faced this matrix while proposing an approximate solution for a dynamic system. Proving invertibility of $M$ equals proving solve-ability of the dynamic system.

- This matrix is symmetric but this property does not seem such helpful for proving invertibility.
- The denominator of this matrix is added by one when moving one cell toward left or above, but it also does not seem very helpful for proving existence of determinant.
- I tried to use Matlab for computing the determinants and induce a rule from them. However, for $m>5$ Matlab does not compute it exactly (i.e. $\text{inv}(M)\cdot M\neq I_{m+1}$).

May anyone provide any hint for proving invertibility of $M$?

Comment: That's a Hilbert matrix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi_j(x)=x^{m+1-j}$, $j=0,\ldots,m$. Then your matrix $M$
is the Gram matrix of the elements $\phi_0,\ldots,\phi_m$
with respect to the positive definite inner product
$$\left<f,g\right>=\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$$
on the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$.
As the $\phi_j$ are linearly independent, then $M$ is positive definite.